# show name instead of email in auto complete list in android login activity

Tags: android, autocomplete

I have an android login activity, and save user name after first login. 
In next login, I want to show user name in auto complete list instead of email. For example, when I type my email, after typing 2-3 letters, I want to see my name in auto complete list to select.

email1 --> show name1

email2 --> show name2

Answer (score 0):

use this in your EditText

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```